# The "Oblivion prophecy"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion, the-elder-scrolls-series

There are known prophecies for Nerevarine and the Dragonborn. Is there any prophecy for the guy in Oblivion known as the Champion of Cyrodiil or the Hero of Kvatch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there was, the Prophecy of Alduin's return and the Dovankin predicted the Oblivion Crisis as you can see it on Alduin's Wall, you can read more about the translation of the wall [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Prophecy_of_the_Dragonborn#Prophecy_of_the_Dragonborn)

Not only does it predict the Oblivion Crisis and Alduin's return but it predicted the events of Arena, Daggerfall and Morrowind and even the start of the Civil War in Skyrim. the Wall was made long before them by the Akaviri and, as per most prophecies, came from an Elder Scroll.

Of course the prophecy of the Oblivion Crisis wouldn't be a step-by-step guide like "a prisoner is going to receive the amulet of kings, find the last heir at Kvatch, stop Mehrunes Dagon's Mythic Dawn and the heir is going to sacrifice himself and the Amulet of Kings to become an avatar of Akatosh", no it's going to be obscured in riddles and metaphors which wont become clear until the time actually comes

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The prophecy is told to you during the very opening. The Emperor tells you of his dreams, where he foresaw the Siege of Bruma. During his escape, he tells you that you're the person he saw in his dreams, which is why he gave you the Amulet of Kings in the first place

In Skyrim they etch the prophecy into a wall, but the prophecy in Oblivion is not recorded anywhere. Only The Emperor has ever seen it, and he never told anyone about it